# In php/html code how do I reference a drupal 7 view and pass a variable?

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-views

Working on  a site, I found that previous developer had a lot of hard coded php to site.  I need to turn something around very quickly and don't have the time to implement drupal features to this.

The programmer had his:

```
<a href="${nurl}"  data-bylink="${sport_url_get}" class="bspyu">
```

This is actually a link to another site.  I am adding another view to a detail page, I want the above link to point to my view and pass the NID so the specific detail object will be queries.  For example I want to transform the above url to something like:

```
<a href=newview/13  class="byu">
```

How can I do this in this php/html code.  The more exact question is, in my php/html code how do I reference a drupal view and pass a variable?

Comment: A full page view is 'referenced' by its URL. So you just need to output `<a href="newview/<?php echo $node->nid; ?>">...</a>`. Whether a node object is available in your current context is impossible to say without more information

Comment: I am investigating that now - the node object - I don't think this is the case.